# Deleting the Global Temp table and then creating the Global temp table with same name is giving ambiguity error

Tags: sql, asp.net

Below is the SQL statement for Deleting the global temp table and creating it again.

```
if object_ID('tempdb..##TempTable123') is not null 
begin drop table  tempdb..##TempTable123 end
GO
Select * into ##TempTable123 from ##TempTable1
```

After executing the Select statement, I am getting the following Error
"The reference to temp table name '##TempTable123' is ambiguous and cannot be resolved. Use either '##TempTable123' or '##TempTable123'."

Comment: The above code works fine when fired in SQL and Fails when fired from .Net

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `tempdb..` to the select:

```
Select * into tempdb..##TempTable123 from tempdb..##TempTable1
```